# Changing boolean values using eventListener

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an etch-a-sketch project. I have a function that paints squares black if "black variable" is true. Moreover, I have another function(it is a button on click effect function) which is capable of turning "black variable" into false and painting squares with random generated colours. However, I cannot create a button which turns "black variable" into true. BlackButton function doesn't work even though tileRainbow function works. Only the last function doesn't work.

I tried altering the function, change the order of functions.

```
const tiles = document.getElementsByClassName("newDiv")
let black = true
//paint squares black on mouseover effect if black is true
function tileBlack() {
    if (black == true) {
        for (tile of tiles) {
            tile.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            })
        }
    }
}
//make rainbow button capable of changing black variable to false. if it is false paint squares with random generated colours.
function rainbowTile() {
    black = false;
    const rainbow = document.querySelector("#rainbow")
    rainbow.addEventListener('click', event => {
        if (black !== true) {
            for (tile of tiles) {

                let randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
                let randomnum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
                let randomnum3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
                tile.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
                    event.target.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${randomnum}, ${randomnum2}, ${randomnum3})`;
                })
            }
        }
    })
}

//make black button capable of changing black variable to true so tileBlack function activates.
function blackButton() {
    const paintitblack = document.querySelector("#black")
    paintitblack.addEventListener('click', event => {
        black = true;
    })
}
```

I do not get any error on console. However, my code doesn't work.

Comment: What calls `rainbowTile()`?

Comment: I called all the functions in my editor. However, I did not add them here.

Comment: Clicking a button calls rainbowTile() function. There is no problem with it. It changes black variable to false and paints squares with random colours. However, It seems like my blackButton() function doesn't work if I click the button. Squares are still painted with random generated colours.

Comment: Adding an event handler *inside* an event handler is almost always the wrong thing to do. Event handlers added via `addEventListener()` are **cumulative** — adding another one does not affect those previously added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be testing the variable when calling `addEventListener()`. If you call both `tileBlack()` and `rainbowTile()`, the tiles have both event listeners.

Instead, you should add a single event listener once, and it should check the variable when it runs.

```js
Array.from(tiles).forEach(tile => tile.addEventListener("mouseover", event => {
  if (black) {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  } else {
    let randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
    let randomnum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
    let randomnum3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
    tile.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${randomnum}, ${randomnum2}, ${randomnum3})`;
    })
  }
}););
```